# Sending parts of form using jQuery serialize() and AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, serialization

I'm trying to send parts of one form by AJAX using jQuery's serialize. The form has 16 textfields. I have 4 buttons. The `button0` sends the textfields 0,1,2,3, and `button1` sends the textfields 4,5,6,7, etc etc. How can I do it?

HTML

```
<html>
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Serialize</title>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>   
 </head>
 <body>
    <form id='miForm' class='miForm' name='miForm' action='env.php' method='POST'>

    </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

jQuery:

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
        for(i=0;i<16;i++){
            $('form').append('Campo de texto '+i+'<input type="text" id="txt'+i+'" value="Campo '+i+'" readonly="yes"/><br>');
        }
        for(i=0;i<4;i++){
            $('form').append('<input type="button" id="butEnv'+i+'" value="Enviar'+i+'"/><br>');
        }
        $('form').append('<input type="button" id="butGen" value="Enviar Global"/><br>');

    });
```

Comment: Can i see your html code here?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use 4 separate forms? Are there any scenarios where it's valid to send more than 4 fields at a time?

Comment: Yes, I want. For example, if I press button0, I only want to send the text0, text1, text2, text3, txt4. And the same for the rest of buttons

Comment: In that case, you definitely want 4 separate forms (even if they all send to the same action) - that eliminates the possibility of the user sending back more than 4 fields at a time, and simplifies the javascript - and best of all, means this will work even without javascript. Can I give you an answer based on this?

Comment: @Beejamin: Can I do it  in only one form?

Comment: Yes, you can, but that's ignoring the way HTML forms are designed to work, and then having to re-create the standard behaviour yourself in javascript. Better to use the standard behaviour wherever you can. Visually, it can still look like a single form...

Comment: why are you stuck on using only one form?

Comment: @jal that doesn't answer why you only want one form

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you really want to stay with only one form try something like I did in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yCpzx/6/).

Create sub parts for your form.

```
<form>
    <div id="first">
        <input name="tbox1" type="text">
        <input name="tbox2" type="text">
        <input name="tbox3" type="text">    
        <input id="button1" type="button" value="button1">  
    </div>
    <div id="second">
        <input name="tbox4" type="text">
        <input name="tbox5" type="text">
        <input name="tbox6" type="text">    
        <input id="button2" type="button" value="button2">  
    </div>
</form>
```

And then just select all the elements of the parts:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button1').on('click', function() {
        alert($('#first input').serialize());
    });

      $('#button2').on('click', function() {
        alert($('#second input').serialize());
    });
});
```

Of course if you also have select boxes you have to add them to the selectors. For example:

```
$('#second input, #second select').serialize()
```

Comment: You can also just simply use $('#second *[name]') selector to select any element that has a name attribute (button, input, select, textarea). jQuery won't serialize non-form submission based tags or the new HTML 5 form tags (keygen, output).  http://jsfiddle.net/bVEd7/

Answer (score 3):

Try [DEMO and CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/m89tu/3/)

Example, modify to your needs:

```
<form name="test">
    <input type="textinput" name="first" value="test1" class="form2" /> <br/>
    <select name="second" class="form1">
        <option value="1">opt 1</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="2">opt 2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="textinput" name="third" value="test1" class="form2" /> <br/>
</form>

<script>
(function() {
    // get second form elements
    var options = $('form[name=test]').find('input, textarea, select').filter('.form2').serialize(); 

    alert(options);

}())
</script>
```

This will get all inputs that have form2 class.

Answer (score 2):

A more semantic and granular approach is to use custom properties to select the different form parts. Makes it easier to reassign form elements to different buttons without messing with containers.

```js
$('button[name="button1"]').click(function() {
  data = $('[scope="part1"]').serialize();
  console.log(data);
});
$('button[name="button2"]').click(function() {
  data = $('[scope="part2"]').serialize();
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="text1" scope="part1" />
  <input type="text" name="text2" scope="part1" />
  <input type="text" name="text3" scope="part1" />
  <input type="text" name="text4" scope="part1" />
  <button type="button" name="button1">Button 1</button>
  <input type="text" name="text5" scope="part2" />
  <input type="text" name="text6" scope="part2" />
  <input type="text" name="text7" scope="part2" />
  <input type="text" name="text8" scope="part2" />
  <button type="button" name="button2">Button 2</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var formData    =    $(form).find('#selectedOptions : input') . serialize();
         $.post(url, formData)  .done(function (data) 
         {  
             alert('hi');
        });

where #selectedOptions is id of the element.
```

Comment: Hi Rakesh Kumar, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I have a comment about your answer: the code you have suggested looks promising, but with some context it would make a better answer; for example, you could explain how and why this proposed change would resolve the questioner's problem, perhaps including a link to the relevant documentation. That would make it more useful to them, and also more useful to other site readers who are looking for solutions to similar problems.