# Excluding fields with specific value from find, serialize Jquery

Tags: jquery

i'm having a problem with jQuery

I want to exclude some fields from being serialized if they have a specific value. In my case the value is all

I'm using

```
jQuery("#charter-form").find("select,input").serialize()
```

and the results is

> lease=rent&type=all&lengthfrom=10&lengthto=60&yacht_name=all&from=all&to=all&number_of_guests=all

i want my result to be

> lease=rent&lengthfrom=10&lengthto=60"

I've tried using `[value!='all']`, `.not`, `contains` etc but I didn't have any luck
thanks for your time

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending parts of form using jQuery serialize() and AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16130619/sending-parts-of-form-using-jquery-serialize-and-ajax)

Comment: This issue has been addressed before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16130619/sending-parts-of-form-using-jquery-serialize-and-ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter out the empty values

```
jQuery("#charter-form").find("select,input").filter(function(){
  return !(this.value === '');
}).serialize()
```