# Django and Ajax - Submitting Formsets

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I've a problem trying to submit a formset through Ajax. A little informaton of what I'm doing is that the user enters a word and through Ajax I get the length of of it and produce a formset according to that number. I then print it out with a for loop and each form has a valid button that its suppose to submit that specific format to validate it. So its a single form submit for each button. Here is my code:

```
<div id="example1" type="hidden">
  {{ exampleForm.management_form }}
      {% for form in exampleForm %}
          <form onsubmit="return false;" method="GET" id="{{ form.prefix }}" >
          ( {{ form.letterOfWord }} + {{ form.keyToUse }} ) MOD 26 =
            {{ form.letterToFill }} <button name="action" id="validateButton" value="validate"> Validate </button>  <br>
          </form>

      {% endfor %}
```

And my javascript file:

```
  $("#validateButton").on({
  click : function() {
    // var variable = document.getElementById('id_plaintext');
    // console.log(variable.value)
    console.log("Inside validate button function")
    var serializedData = $('form').serialize();
    console.log(serializeData);
    $.ajax( {
      url: "/exampleCaesar",
      type : "GET",
      data: { CSRF: 'csrf_token',
              serializedData
      },

      success : function(exampleData) {

      console.log(exampleData)


      }

    }); //END OF Ajax
  } //END OF FUNCTION


 }); //END OF validateButton
```

Thing is that when I click any of the validate buttons, nothing is submitted. I know this because I got a `console.log` in the javascript to know when it goes in. If that doesnt print out then it didn't actually go in.

Any tips? Been breaking my head all day for this. Thanks

Comment: console.log("Inside validate button function") gets printed?

Comment: No it doesn't. Thats how I know its not getting submitted correctly.

Comment: Well is should. it just prints is the button validateButton was executed. not the ajax. so your buttons is not  executed aat all..

Comment: Yeah I know its not executed. Like one of the answers says, it could be with the IDs of the buttons that are the same...

Comment: click : function(e) { and add e.preventDefault()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101231/discussion-between-silvestrini-and-ilan-hasanov).

Answer (score 1):

you have multiple IDs `validateButton`. This might be source of your problems. As far as I know, or would guess, jquery will only trigger on the first button of the first form in this case.

Also, I'm not sure if jquery will serialize proper form when you use this code

```
var serializedData = $('form').serialize();
```

as again, you have multiple `form` in your html

Also, the `managment_form` should be inside of `<form>`, otherwise it won't get sent to Django. Check out the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/formsets/#using-a-formset-in-views-and-templates

Comment: Then how could I set up X amount of buttons for the formset with different names? And also if I do this, then how can I get it called to Ajax if I don't know how many buttons there will be? I'm trying to submit each form individually.

Comment: just use css class. I'm not sure what do you mean by calling ajax if you don't know how many forms there will be... ajax just processes the click on any button with proper class. If you want to name them, then use some form identification, I think in django templates you can use {{ form.instance.pk }} and concatenate it with button id

Comment: this is the correct answer, there is only one form if you want to make a different request per form in formset you have to use classes not id's and serialize only part of the form, you can refer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16130619/sending-parts-of-form-using-jquery-serialize-and-ajax to do that

Comment: What I mean is that, for example we get the word STACK which has 5 letters. With this five letters I generate a formset of 5 sets of forms. Each form has a validate button that when the user enters an information in each blank form and hits validate, its suppose to go to the Javascript file, find the validateButton tag and go through Ajax to send that information to the view and the view responds back.

Comment: yes, but you don't need to use special IDs. you can navigate everywhere in jquery in success function. You can navigate through that button that got clicked, for example with parent() function you can get to coresponding form and then use some more navigation to print out the response. see this for finding the button clicked https://api.jquery.com/event.target/

Comment: I tried and still couldn't get inside the JQuery. Can you explain a little more your last suggestion?